# Uploaded photo's won't go into the uploads/ folder

Tags: php, file-upload

I am using the w3Schools [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) to create my *upload.php* file and have all the code correctly finished - Although it seems to be correct according to the tutorial the images that I upload to the website will not 'deposit' into the folder that it is setup to.

My *upload.php*

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOK = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//Check if image file is an actual image or a fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOK = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOK = 0;
    }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOK = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOK = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "png") {
    echo "Sorry, only PNG files are allowed.";
    $uploadOK = 0;
}

?>
```

This is the screen I get when I attempt to upload a photo that is part of the *'requirements'* :
[image: Result of upload]

The "uploads/" folder is located in the same directory as the upload.php but as I said the files are still not going anywhere. Thank you in advance for any help.

Best regards,
Codi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move everything inside the `$_POST["submit"]` block and then use the `move_uploaded_file()` line at the end

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOK = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOK = 0;
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOK = 0;
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOK = 0;
    }

    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "png") {
        echo "Sorry, only PNG files are allowed.";
        $uploadOK = 0;
    }

    if($uploadOK)
    {
        chmod($target_dir, 0750); // just to make sure the target folder is writable
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);)
        {
            echo 'File uploaded succesfully';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'There was a problem uploading the file';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Upload cannot take place as the validation failed';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't use move_uploaded_file() function. Without that function, file will not move to the folder.

Comment: Alright, thank you where exactly would I put that function in the upload.php and what would I put in the ( )'s ? Perhaps provide me an example using my code if that is ok?

Comment: In else part put this code..        else {
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    }

Comment: this code already in the w3school link, u provide in ur question. at the last.check it

Comment: Sorry for the hassle, I put the code in exactly as you said and nothing has really changed as far as it functions as it should. Here is an image of the code that I put in according to the code you provided: http://imgur.com/BRjqMvP

Comment: in the form, did you provide text field name "filetoupload" and enctype property to form??

Comment: looked back at the tutorial where you received the code from and seemed to work when I put the code in. Not sure why it didn't work the first time, thank you for the help!